# RabbitMQ not working when services are dockerized

Tags: spring-boot, docker, rabbitmq

So I have 2 services. `Kweet` (which is a tweet) and `User`. When I run the 2 services manually + rest of the services in docker, it works. Rest of services include `MongoDB`, `RabbitMQ`, `Spring Cloud Gateway`, `Eureka Discovery`. But the moment I run the 2 (micro)services in Docker (I just use a docker compose), the rabbitmq functionality stops working. The normal API calls work, it's specifically the RabbitMQ calls that fail.

RabbitMQ functionality:

```
EditUsername, edits username in user-service. 
Than sends data via RabbitMQ (this is where it goes wrong I think) to kweet-service where it edits the username of a kweet.
```

Docker-compose file:

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  eureka-service:
    build: ./eureka-discovery-service
    restart: always
    container_name: eureka-service
    ports:
      - 8087:8087

  api-gateway:
    build: ./api-gateway
    restart: always
    container_name: api-gateway
    depends_on:
      - eureka-service
    ports:
      - 8080:8080

  user:
    build: ./user
    restart: unless-stopped
    container_name: user-ms
    ports:
      - 8081:8081
    depends_on:
      - eureka-service

  kweet:
    build: ./kweet
    restart: unless-stopped
    container_name: kweet-ms
    depends_on:
      - eureka-service
    ports:
    - 8082:8082

  mongodb:
    image: mongo
    restart: always
    container_name: mongodb
    ports:
      - 27017:27017

  rabbitmq:
    image: rabbitmq:management
    restart: always
    container_name: rabbitmq
    hostname: rabbitmq
    ports:
      - 5672:5672
      - 15672:15672
```

When I try to make a call the console shows:

```
user-ms  |  2022-04-27 08:52:04.823  INFO 1 --- [nio-8081-exec-4] o.s.a.r.c.CachingConnectionFactory : Attempting to connect to: [localhost:5672]
```

The postman status I get back is `503 Service Unavailable` which **isn't** from any `try-catch`'s I made. Anybody have any clue where the problem might be?

**EDIT[ConnectionFactory]:**
I tried to use the documentation and added a the `CachingConnectionFactory` but it had the same result. Am I doing it wrong?
I added this to the RabbitMQ/Message-config (HOST, USERNAME, PASSWORD come from `application.properties`:

```
@Bean
    public AmqpTemplate template() {
        CachingConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new CachingConnectionFactory(HOST);
        connectionFactory.setUsername(USERNAME);
        connectionFactory.setPassword(PASSWORD);
        final RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate = new RabbitTemplate(connectionFactory);
        rabbitTemplate.setMessageConverter(converter());
        return rabbitTemplate;
    }
```

**EDIT [docker-compose]:**
Found this source (https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/binding-your-docker-app-container-rabbitmq-phani-bushan/) that got rid of my `503 Service Unavailable` error. The problem I found now is that whenever I start up the containers, it generates new queues and exchanges that aren't the ones [I set up in my application.properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iewzj.jpg).

Now whenever I make a call, it shows this log:

```
user-ms | 2022-04-28 07:36:28.825  INFO 1 --- [nio-8081-exec-1] o.s.a.r.c.CachingConnectionFactory : Created new connection: rabbitConnectionFactory#2ca65ce4:0/SimpleCo
nnection@7e7052f [delegate=amqp://guest@172.23.0.4:5672/, localPort= 43208]
```

Things tried:

- change host to [rabbitmq-container-name] in code via `CachingConnectionFactory`
- change host to [rabbitmq-container-name] in docker compose with `environment: - spring_rabbitmq_host=[rabbitmq-container-name]`

```
  build: ./user
  restart: unless-stopped
  container_name: user-ms
  depends_on:
    - eureka-service
    - rabbitmq
  ports:
    - 8081:8081
  environment:
    - spring_rabbitmq_host=[rabbitmq-container-name]
```

- Instead of [rabbitmq-container-name] I've tried `host.docker.internal` and `localhost`

Comment: have you read the logs from rabbitmq service? I'm pretty sure you need to configure user access before starting the docker version.

Comment: What am I supposed to find in the logs? I'm still new to docker and rabbitmq, but I can login to the rabbitmq management UI if that's what it means. No exchanges or queues were made though (when making the call).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have made a grave mistake. 2 things that I did before it started working.

1. Change Dockerfile `ADD` command to `COPY` (Don't think that was the problem though)
2. Deleted all my images and containers and re-made them a.k.a instead of `docker-compose up` I should've been typing `docker-compose up --build`. This was most likely the issue

```
brb gonna cry in a corner
```

Answer (score 3):

When you dockerize your services are no longer listening in `localhost`. If you need to network connect services you need to use container_name instead of localhost.

localhost points to the container itself, where only one service is listening. Do not mistake for when you develop on your laptop without containers, where everything is in localhost

More about this [here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/)

> By default Compose sets up a single network for your app. Each container for a service joins the default network and is both reachable by other containers on that network, and discoverable by them at a hostname identical to the container name.

You must configure, somewhere in your `user-ms` application (we do not know what kind of applicatin is), that RabbitMQ service is listening at `rabbitmq` (container_name) not `localhost`.

Comment: Nowhere in my user-service refers to the rabbitmq service. I just have a amqp maven dependency and made `rabbit/messageConfig`. With a template, no references to the rabbitmq service. Also about the container_name, I do have that in my yml's for the `eureka-service`. I'll add it to the post

Comment: You have to add the docker containers for the 2 microservices and the RabbitMQ container in a single docker network. Port mapping won't help you much, because it only makes the RabbitMQ service visible to your local machine, not to the microservices containers. You'll also need to adjust RabbitMQ connection in the microservices to point to the hostname or ip address of the RabbitMQ container, not localhost

Comment: You can read about configuring RabbitMQ host and port like [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/current/reference/html/#cachingconnectionfactory)

Comment: @Nenad But the microservices and rabbitmq-container are both already in the same default docker network (I checked with `docker container inspect [container_id]`). And how do I adjust the rabbitMQ connection if there is none in the code? This is the tutorial I used: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o4qCdBR4gUM&t=314s

Comment: Even if the containers belong to the same network by default, you can't access the RabbitMQ container with localhost. If you use the default network, you will probably need to use the IP address of the RabbitMQ container. There is a link how to configure RabbitMQ connection in the previous comment by @usuario

Comment: @Nenad I tried to add username, password and host kind of like they did. But it didn't seem to work. I edited it in the post (2), that's how I'm supposed to configure it right?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the container with environment variables. For me it is enough for working.

```yaml
  rabbitmq:
    image: rabbitmq:management
    restart: always
    container_name: rabbitmq
    environment:
      RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER: guest
      RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS: guest
      RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_VHOST: /
    ports:
      - 5672:5672
      - 15672:15672
```

I can open this container in a browser: http://localhost:15672/

I use PHP FPM and Symfony and I pass env value to this container to connect to rabbitmq.

```yaml
services:
    php-fpm:
        environment:
            ENQUEUE_DSN: amqp://guest:guest@rabbitmq:5672
```

For Java you need to find and define or redefine application properties. The config may use the default value for localhost, like this `spring.rabbitmq.host=localhost`, but you need to use Docker's host, it is `rabbitmq`.

```
spring.rabbitmq.host=rabbitmq
spring.rabbitmq.port=5672
spring.rabbitmq.username=guest
spring.rabbitmq.password=guest
```

Comment: So you can make rabbitmq calls from a service that is running in docker? Because I tried that as well, but still same log shows us with error 503

Comment: Of course. I use it thought env of another container that - PHP FPM. `ENQUEUE_DSN: amqp://guest:guest@rabbitmq:5672`

Comment: Wait, so where do I put the second part? And what is it for? I don't understand..

Comment: If you use rabbitmq in other services you need to configure it, you need to set a path or settings of rabbitmq to another service that uses rabbitmq. 
For example, my PHP project use rabbitmq, but I need to set my app with rabbitmq's DSN to connect PHP and RabbitMQ. Without this config it doesn't work, because PHP doesn't know whom send requests.

Comment: But in the tutorial I used there wasn't something like that in it. So I don't know if there is something similar like that in Spring Boot. (Tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o4qCdBR4gUM&t=314s)

Comment: I've found your project must have application properties for your rabbit:  spring.rabbitmq.host=localhost spring.rabbitmq.port=5672 spring.rabbitmq.username=guest spring.rabbitmq.password=guest, but you need use `rabbitmq` instead of `localhost`, it is a name from `docker-compose`.

Comment: In this video a man use localhost, because he doesn't use docker, but you need to connect two services. You have to find and change default settings for rabbitmq, change host.